# pjsip c#, System.AccessViolationException on answering an incoming call on an separated thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, sip, pjsip

In the `overrided void onIncomingCall` I open a new Background thread which shows a `new (Popup) Form`.
I try to pickup or decline the Call in this Form but then I get an `System.AccessViolationException.`
it seems that the current call object is locked and cannot be accessed from another Form.
If I use the `currentcall.answer(prm)` in the `onIncomingCall` void then the call is established successfully (without another Form and thread).

```
public class myaccount : Account
{

   public override void onIncomingCall(OnIncomingCallParam prm)
   {
       Call call = new Call(this, prm.callId);
       CallOpParam param = new CallOpParam();


       param.statusCode = pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_RINGING;
       param.statusCode = pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_OK;
       pjsipfunctions.currentparam = param;
       pjsipfunctions.currentcall = call;


       var thread = new Thread(() =>
       {
           ShowPopup(call,prm.callId.ToString());

       });
       thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       thread.Start();

       //    Thread myCallingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowPopup));
       //myCallingThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
       //myCallingThread.IsBackground = true;
       //myCallingThread.Start();



   }
   public void ShowPopup(Call myCall,string call_id)
   {
       IncommingCallPopup win = new IncommingCallPopup(ref myCall, call_id );

       win.Show();
       System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();


     }


}

#####################################
public IncommingCallPopup(ref  Call info, string callid)
   {
       currentCall = info;
        Callid = callid;
       CurrentCall = currentCall;
       Prm.statusCode = pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_RINGING;
       InitializeComponent();
       labelCallId.Content = callid;

   }

   private void rejectcall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       Prm.statusCode = pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_DECLINE;
       CurrentCall.hangup(Prm);
   }

   private void transfercall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

   }

   private void takecall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

       Prm.statusCode = pjsip_status_code.PJSIP_SC_OK;
       try
       {
           CurrentCall.answer(Prm);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {

       }

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

After crazy searching and trying some things i've figured it out.
Every Thread must registered in the Endpoint that you can hangup, pickup or transfer your call in another Class(Window).

All you need is to write this Method in a Public class and call this void everytime you call your void from another window ->

```
public void callpopup(String number) {
     checkThread();

//answer, decline or something else

}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
    public static void checkThread()
    {
        try
        {

            if (ep != null && !ep.libIsThreadRegistered())
                ep.libRegisterThread(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {


        }
    }
```

Comment: EP refeer to the Endpoint instance. Please note that threads from a thread pool don't have a name. Make sure to assign a name to them or a null reference exception may happen.